# How do I put these xml-apis.jar, stax-apis.jar or xercesImpl.jar :to my pom,xml

Tags: java, apache-poi, jira-plugin

I get this trece on JIRA plugin in Apache POI:

Here is Caused by with Apache POI 3.9:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook]:      
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory; at  
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115) at

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory; at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller
```

I looked this FAQ from Apache POI
http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1017E

How do I put these xml-apis.jar, stax-apis.jar or xercesImpl.jar :to my pom,xml dependencies.

Comment: Do you want to add the dependencies or exclude them?

Comment: Yes I want to add these to dependencies

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? Why not use the latest? (Currently 3.12)

Comment: Sorry I am useing lates Apache POI. I just made mistype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, you just need to declare the new dependencies in the "dependencies" section. Here you have a directory with the different versions, search the one you need and add them:

XML-Apis: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis

Xerces: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces

Stax-apis: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stax/stax-api

Comment: Now it works when I use Apache POI 3.9 but it makes a corrupted file.